# How to use LINQ query in C# to filter data by empty or single string or string array

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I have a string parameter 'type' to my method, which can be null, single value or multiple values separated by comma as follows:

```
string type=null; //should return all rows
string type="java"; //should return data with java 
string type="xamarin,java,c#"; //should return data with all these 3 options
string type="invalid"; //should return null
```

I need to return all rows if type is empty else return only the rows matching the string array.

I am using following LINQ in my server side cs file:

```
public object filter(string type)
{
var models = context. /// get data from db, with id,Date,type,comment as columns
return models.Where(v=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) ? true : type.Split(',').Contains(v.type)
.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).ToList();

}
```

> When i pass null, it returns all row - seems working
>
> When i pass type separated by comma, it return rows of all types -
>   seems working
>
> **When i pass invalid type, it should return zero rows (Not working)**

I am expecting a clean and single line solution.

Comment: what are you getting back when you pass invalid type?

Comment: What you mean by "Not working"?

Comment: I have tried your code out, it works, i get empty list, if i provide "invalid" as paramater

Comment: I am getting all results when i pass "invalid" value to my type. I don't know if I am missing something . And also, I should be able to get results if i pass "java,invalid" where it returns only data with type "java"

Answer (score 0):

You want this result

```
string type="invalid"; //should return null
```

but in you code this condition is not processed

```
return type.Split(',').Contains("invalid") ? null : models
       .Where(v=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) ? true : type.Split(',').Contains(v.type)
       .OrderByDescending(a => a.Date)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: it is not always 'invalid'; it can be anything and if that string is not present in my data, it should return null

Comment: @LearnByExample, I'm sorry, perhaps I misunderstood formulation of the question. If you need to process all types of incorrect, you should correct part with `contains` and add something like this `...type.Split ( ','). Contains (v.type)? true: *handle type mismatch*`. But I really don't understand why you needed blank entries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks friends, it works perfectly for any case.

```
return models.Where(v => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type) ? true : type.Split(',').Contains(v.type) ).OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: So the only difference was `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `IsNullOrEmpty`?  I don;t think that's very helpful as an asnwer unless you explain how that fixed the problem of passing in `"invalid"`

Comment: @Stanley . Yes, you are correct it doesn't matter anything . The original solution was working. there was some mistake in the following code snippets.